# How to customize Worklist control in K2 smartforms?

Tags: workflow, k2

I am using worklist control in my form to follow the work processes in case of forms.  And i want to customize this control. It has a default format that allows to right click, select next step in the list directly, open form or view flow as follows.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsmtT.jpg

But, i need to disable that submenu. Instead of that, when i double clicked on a work, it must be open the form directly. And the user must see the form before approved certainly. The thing that i wanted is a simple difference. But designer doesn't allow to change. Can i edit this situation somehow?
Is that possible?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There's currently no way of customising the worklist control that is out of the box.

However, you can build your own worklist control using this broker available on the community.

http://community.k2.com/t5/K2-blackpearl/Worklist-Service-Broker/ba-p/889

The worklist broker will generate SmartObjects that allow you to wired them to a list view.

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of K2 (4.6.11) allows a little more configuration of the Worklist control. You may choose the buttons and columns that are displayed by default.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create custom worklist in K2 Designer. Firstly, create SMO from Worklist Service. Then you have to make custom SP for generate data and 1 folio column folio. Finally, Create SMO from SP step 2 and associate it using SMO edit in K2 Designer.